# XSL Not returning any data when applied to a XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML which looks like this below and is represented by this URL http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tag/@sponsor_bluemoon-general/feed

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
  <title>sponsor_bluemoon General on Huffington Post</title>
  <link href="http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tag/@sponsor_bluemoon-general/feed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tag/%40sponsor_bluemoon-general"/>
  <logo>
    http://s.huffpost.com/images/HuffingtonPost_250x20.png
  </logo>
  <id>
    tag:www.huffingtonpost.com,2014:/tag/%40sponsor_bluemoon-general
  </id>
  <updated>2014-07-24T08:03:25Z</updated>
  <generator uri="http://www.huffingtonpost.com/">Huffington Post</generator>

  <entry>
    <title>
      The Second Half Of The MLB Season Is Going To Be Intense
    </title>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/24/ranking-the-mlb-division-_n_5610682.html"/>
    <id>
      http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/24/ranking-the-mlb-division-_n_5610682.html
    </id>
    <published>2014-07-24T08:03:25Z</published>
    <updated>2014-07-24T08:03:28Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>The Huffington Post News Team</name>
      <uri>http://www.huffingtonpost.com/the-news/</uri>
    </author>
    <content type="html" xml:lang="en-US" xml:base="http://www.huffingtonpost.com/">
    It's going to be a fun, and very intense, second half of the baseball season. <br /> <br /> By the All-Star break, one division in the National League had a tie... <p>Read more: <a href="/tag/brew-pub">Brew-Pub</a>, <a href="/tag/baseball">Baseball</a>, <a href="/tag/mlb">Mlb</a>, <a href="/tag/major-league-baseball">Major League Baseball</a>, <a href="/tag/mlb-division-races">Mlb Division Races</a>, <a href="/sports">Sports News</a></p>
    </content>
    <link href="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1924460/thumbs/s-OAKLAND-ANGELS-154x114.jpg" type="image/jpeg" rel="enclosure"/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

The  nodes are repeated and hence I am "for each"ing those entry node to extract title author id link and content. Right now I have written xsl to extract only the author and title. But my xsl doesn't return anything. 
My XSL Looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
            <channel>
                <author>
                    <xsl:text>Content-Feed-Pics</xsl:text>
                </author>
                <xsl:for-each select="xml//entry[position() &lt; 10]">
                    <item>
                        <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                        <author><xsl:value-of select="author/name"/></author>
                      <!-- <icon>
                       <xsl:value-of select="concat(entities/media//media_url,':thumb')"/>                    
                       </icon>-->


                        <!--link><xsl:value-of select="entities/media//media_url"/></link-->
                        <!--description><xsl:value-of select="text"/></description>
                        <pubDate><xsl:value-of select="created_at"/></pubDate-->
                       <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="entities/media//media_url"/>-->
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </channel>
        </rss>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--xsl:template match="entities/media//media_url"-->
      <!--  <enclosure>
                          <xsl:attribute name="url">
                         <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ':thumb')" />
                         </xsl:attribute>
                         <xsl:attribute name="type">
                          <xsl:text>image/jpg</xsl:text>
                          </xsl:attribute>
        </enclosure>-->
 <!--/xsl:template-->
</xsl:stylesheet>
​
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. **Before using xml//entry I used feed/entry and //entry but that didn't works as well.**
Please advice.

My xsl for http://feeds.contenthub.aol.com/syndication/2.0/feed/53d27420b4075 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
            <channel>
                <author>
                    <xsl:text>Content-Feed-Pics</xsl:text>
                </author>
                <!--xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[position() &lt; 30]"-->
                    <item>
                        <title><xsl:value-of select="rss/channel/item/title"/></title>
                        <author><xsl:value-of select="rss/channel/item/dc:creator"/></author>
                       <!--icon>
                       <xsl:value-of select="concat(entities/media//media_url,':thumb')"/>                    
                       </icon-->


                        <link><xsl:value-of select="rss/channel/item/link"/></link>
                        <description><xsl:value-of select="rss/channel/item/description"/></description>
                        <!--pubDate><xsl:value-of select="created_at"/></pubDate-->
                    </item>
                <!--/xsl:for-each-->
            </channel>
        </rss>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What do you think `select="xml//entry[position() &lt; 10]"` is supposed to do?

Comment: @torazaburo It is supposed to cycle through entry nodes I have tried feed/entry, xml/feed/entry but nothing worked.

Comment: Your input XML is broken. There is no closing tag for `<feed>`. I'm very surprised your XSL processor did not report an error. Once you have a properly formatted XML input, and you want to access the `<entry>` elements, then use `//entry`. However, `for-each` is an anti-pattern in XSL. Instead, write specific templates designed to match specific patterns, such as `<xsl:template match="entry">`.

Comment: @torazaburo The xml is properly formatted.http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tag/@sponsor_bluemoon-general/feed and there is closing tag for </feed> so should I use <xsl:template match="entry"> in place of <xsl:template match="/"> What should be in my xsl for each loop

Comment: The XML you posted is **not** well-formed. There is no `</feed>` closing tag. As for your question on how to write XSL, please read an intro to XSL.

Comment: @torazaburo: I don't think that the OP meant that his copy-and-pasted XML was well-formed, he wrote "looks like", and linked to the correct source at the Huffington Post. Of course, it always helps if a question is asked that contains all the information required to reproduce the issue: [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was correct to use `feed/entry` in this case, but your problem (assuming your XML is well-formed), is with that of namespaces.

In the original XML, all the nodes are part of the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace, due to the default namespace declaration on the `feed` element

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

But in your XSLT, where you do (or did) `<xsl:for-each select="feed/entry[position() &lt; 10]">`, then this is look for elements in NO namespace. Such elements are different to ones in a namespace, and so won't be matched.

The solution (in XSLT 1.0, at least) is to ensure the namespace is correctly declared in the XSLT, and prefix all the elements in your XPath with the relevant prefix. For example

```
<xsl:for-each select="atom:feed/atom:entry[position() &lt; 10]">
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com" version="2.0">
            <channel>
                <author>
                    <xsl:text>Content-Feed-Pics</xsl:text>
                </author>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:feed/atom:entry[position() &lt; 10]" />
            </channel>
        </rss>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="atom:entry">
       <item>
           <title><xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/></title>
           <author><xsl:value-of select="atom:author/atom:name"/></author>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I have moved the declaration for the `atom` namespace to the main `xsl:stylesheet` so it can be referenced throughout the XSLT. I have also shown how to use templates here because if nothing else it cuts down on indentation.

Comment: Excellent answer. And... if you can use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, you can use `xpath-default-namespace` on any containing instruction or literal result element, which takes away the tediousness of having to rewrite your code with prefixes for each NameTest in expressions.

Comment: @Tim C Thanks a lot. The only missing puzzle is to get link /@href .There are 2 links one with rel='enclosure' and other with rel='alternate' I want one with rel='enclosure'. Kindly help.

Comment: You would do `<xsl:value-of select="link[@rel='enclosure']" />`

Comment: @TimC Thanks for all your help. The xml's were taken care of by adding atom:. Now I need to access link. title description from <item> node of http://feeds.contenthub.aol.com/syndication/2.0/feed/53d27420b4075. The content is a slide show. I have attached my XSL above in the question but it gives a failed XSL Transformation when I try to access the data. I have taken out the xsl:for each loop since there is only 1 content node.

Comment: If the original question has been answered, you should really be asking a whole new question. SO isn't a discussion forum, and it makes it difficult to follow if a question is continually amended. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC I have created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311394/xsl-scenario-when-a-node-is-not-present-in-every-for-each-loop. It would be great if you could have a look at it. Thanks much.

Comment: @TimC for xml where the namespace is appended for some nodes only lke here http://feeds.contenthub.aol.com/syndication/2.0/feed/53dfbe8362619 where ss:slideshow is the element I want to access. I am not able to access that element . What should be for each loop for <item> look like to access that node.